# Sending OTP before authentication / password verification

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, one-time-password

One of my old, rarely used computers had still an old password for my pyszne.pl / takeaway.com account stored in my browser's password manager. I tried to log into my account from that computer and saw a page saying that a one-time password was sent to an email address associated with the account that I am trying to use. I needed to provide this OTP before continuing.

I waited about 5 minutes until OTP popped in my mailbox and after providing it I was a bit shocked to see a message that the password that I have provided is incorrect. Verifying this in the browser's password manager confirmed the fact.

What am I missing here? What is the reason (or possible advantage) for sending OTP only after validating user name (email address) as existing and before verifying the password?

In all systems, except this one, I have used so far, this was exactly the opposite. First, try to authenticate user/check provided password and only if it is correct, then send the OTP to their email address.

Answer (score 8):

This is certainly not normal. What it can do is protect the account from brute-force login attempts. An attacker will never know if a password is correct or not since they need the OTP from the email to be able to tell.

***However***, this approach has its own problems. For instance, every brute force attempt will result in you getting an email. This can flood your account and make it difficult to log in legitimately if someone is testing your account. So the site is depending on your email service to protect your account instead of using account protections themselves. And you hope that they have some protections against email floods.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @schroeder this is not a common design for two-factor authentication, but it could be used to increase the search space for the attacker who uses a brute-force approach.

However, based on your description of how it works, particularly the fact that it gave you feedback saying that your password is incorrect, I think that the implementation of this uncommon authentication scenario is incorrect. The system should deny your access and only state that your credentials are incorrect. Which one is incorrect (password or OTP)? It should NOT tell you that.

Most OTP authentication servers will limit the number of OTP requests they will send to you per unit of time (e.g. 5 OTP per hour), so it is unlikely that the system will flood your email box with email messages unless it is really a poorly designed authentication system.

Comment: Since the account holder is verified from the OTP *first*, there isn't a problem with providing feedback to the user that the password was incorrect. The OP stated that the OTP was entered first, then the message about the password was provided.

Comment: thank you @schroeder but what if I entered the correct password and the wrong OTP, if I get a message saying "wrong password", then the system really depends on the security of the email services the user  is using, correct?

Comment: If you enter the wrong OTP, you won't get the password message at all. You are assuming the logic flow if the OTP is incorrect.